# Customize Yii2 plugin without touching core vendor folder

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Hi I am using Yii2 plugin for login and user management: https://github.com/webvimark/user-management

I want to customize view files of this plugin. How can I do this without touching to core file in vendor folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize vendor view files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231120/how-to-customize-vendor-view-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [theming](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-theming) to override some view files. In your config:

```
'components' => [
    // ...
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => [
                '@vendor/webvimark/module-user-management/views' => '@app/views/user-management',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Then put your views into `@app/views/user-management` directory.

---

But if extension is not maintained anymore you may consider forking extension, do changes in fork and use it as a dependency.

Comment: yii\base\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid path alias: @webvimark/modules/UserManagement/views in D:\xampp7\htdocs\phprobo_yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php:154

Comment: Are you sore that you have this extension installed?

Comment: Yes. I have that extension installed on location: vendor\webvimark\module-user-management

Comment: See my update. It looks like this extension does not have valid composer type, so related aliases are not registered by Yii.

Comment: Any other authentication library you know for Yii2? Which is fully customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Extent the component/module and the class in your project

Create User Config Class extends from the UserConfig.

```
class YourClass-UserConfig extends webvimark\modules\UserManagement\components\UserConfig
{
/* Custom As you want  */
}
```

and UserManagementModule

```
class YourClass-UserManagementModule extends webvimark\modules\UserManagement\UserManagementModule
{ 
/* Custom As you want */
}
```

and in config add your component

```
components'=>[
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'YourPackage\YourClass-UserConfig',
    ],
],

'modules'=>[
    'user-management' => [
        'class' => 'YourPackage\YourClass-UserManagementModule',
```

In your class custom as you want.